# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages hierarchy with multiple route parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to create an "item" page which is always inside an "inventory" using Razor Pages.

What I don't know is how to provide the `id` of the inventory to the item page

Let's say I have the following Pages structure

`Pages
  Inventories
    Items`

I assume I could have a route similar to `/Inventories/{id}/Items/` and then `/Inventories/{id}/Items/{itemid}` to display a certain item but I'm not sure how. Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In asp.net core 2.1 Razor Pages, you could use [Custom Routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes) to specify a custom route to a page.

```
@page "/Inventories/{id:int}/Items/{itemid:int}"
```

And you could get id by using

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id, int? itemid)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried to do this but I see now that I had missed some details.